# Definition of flatMap in Swift

Tags: swift, monads, functor, flatmap

I was studying a **functor** and **monad**. So I got to know that a functor uses `map` and a monad uses `flatMap`, and also that definition of `map` and `flatMap` looks like below.

```swift
enum Box<T> {
    case some(T)
    case empty
}

extension Box {
    func map<U>(_ f: @escaping (T) -> U) -> Box<U> {
        // ...
    }
}

extension Box {
    func flatMap<U>(_ f: (T) -> Box<U>) -> Box<U> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I totally got those are using different `f` parameter(Thanks for [this article](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/swift-monad-functor-applicative-806bb34c68c5)).

Then, I just wanted to check definition of `map` and `flatMap` in `Optional`, `Result` and `Array`. Because I heard those are monad as well. In `Optional` and `Result`, the definition looks like same as custom `map` and `flatMap` above.

But in `Array`, does not.

```swift
func map<T>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]

func flatMap<SegmentOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.Element] where SegmentOfResult : Sequence
```

I'm bit confused now. Because I knew a monad apply a function that returns wrapped value to wrapped value, so I expected the definition of `flatMap` looking like below(definitely wrong).

```swift
func flatMap<T>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> [T]) rethrows -> [T]
```

But It's not anyway.

Am I missing something? Where is the point that I misunderstood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were expecting

```
func flatMap<T>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> Array<T>) rethrows -> Array<T>
```

for `Array`.

If you look closely, the above is merely a special case of the signature that you found, when `SegmentOfResult == Array<T>`.

The `flatMap` in `Array` is defined not just for the case when `SegmentOfResult == Array<T>`, but also for any `SegmentOfResult` that is a `Sequence`.

Why? Because we would like to define functions so that they work on as many types as possible (i.e. as general as possible). It turns out that `flatMap` would also work if the function mapped to any `Sequence`. That is, it doesn't depend on the fact that the function returns specifically an `Array`. It only depends on the fact that the function returns some kind of a `Sequence`. Check out how `flatMap` is implemented [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L754) if you are interested.

For the same reason, `flatMap` isn't just available on `Array`, it's available on any type that conforms to `Sequence`!

Comment: Thanks for reply. So I use `flatMap` for `Array<T>`, which means `[SegmentOfResult.Element] == Array<T>`? If so, Why? Could you give me any resources about that?

Comment: You mean why does `[SegmentOfResult.Element] == Array<T>`? Well, `SegmentOfResult` is `Array<T>`, and `Array<T>.Element` is `T`, so `[SegmentOfResult.Element]` is `[T]`, which is another way of saying `Array<T>`. @InTaekCho